# how to do I group values for given values

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this kind of values and I need to group them based on some values :

```
{
2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}, 
6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}
}
```

you can see there are two different ids byt will have similar values. so I would like to group them based on the ids.

like in a Hashmap these ids can be keys and rest will become values for the id.

how do I go about to do this.

**EDIT**

how do id split the string and get `id and values` and store them in to a hashmap `Map <String, Item> tag = new HashMap <String, Item> ();` thanks to upog

and this is my Item Class

```
public class Item {
    private String mihpayid;
    private String request_id;
    private String bank_ref_num;
    private String amt;
    private String disc;
    private String mode;
    private String PG_TYPE;
    private String card_no;
    private String name_on_card;
    private String udf2;
    private String addedon;
    private String status;
    private String unmappedstatus;
    private String Merchant_UTR;
    private String Settled_At;

    public String getMihpayid() {
        return mihpayid;
    }
    public void setMihpayid(String mihpayid) {
        this.mihpayid = mihpayid;
    }
    public String getRequest_id() {
        return request_id;
    }
    public void setRequest_id(String request_id) {
        this.request_id = request_id;
    }
    public String getBank_ref_num() {
        return bank_ref_num;
    }
    public void setBank_ref_num(String bank_ref_num) {
        this.bank_ref_num = bank_ref_num;
    }
    public String getAmt() {
        return amt;
    }
    public void setAmt(String amt) {
        this.amt = amt;
    }
    public String getDisc() {
        return disc;
    }
    public void setDisc(String disc) {
        this.disc = disc;
    }
    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }
    public void setMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }
    public String getPG_TYPE() {
        return PG_TYPE;
    }
    public void setPG_TYPE(String pG_TYPE) {
        PG_TYPE = pG_TYPE;
    }
    public String getCard_no() {
        return card_no;
    }
    public void setCard_no(String card_no) {
        this.card_no = card_no;
    }
    public String getName_on_card() {
        return name_on_card;
    }
    public void setName_on_card(String name_on_card) {
        this.name_on_card = name_on_card;
    }
    public String getUdf2() {
        return udf2;
    }
    public void setUdf2(String udf2) {
        this.udf2 = udf2;
    }
    public String getAddedon() {
        return addedon;
    }
    public void setAddedon(String addedon) {
        this.addedon = addedon;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getUnmappedstatus() {
        return unmappedstatus;
    }
    public void setUnmappedstatus(String unmappedstatus) {
        this.unmappedstatus = unmappedstatus;
    }
    public String getMerchant_UTR() {
        return Merchant_UTR;
    }
    public void setMerchant_UTR(String merchant_UTR) {
        Merchant_UTR = merchant_UTR;
    }
    public String getSettled_At() {
        return Settled_At;
    }
    public void setSettled_At(String settled_At) {
        Settled_At = settled_At;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

are you expecting some thing like

```
Map <String, ArrayList<Object>> tag = new HashMap <String, ArrayList<Object>> ();
```

for a single id, you can associate a list of values

**EDIT**
to get value from string

```
     int keyLength =7;   
  String str="{2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}, 6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}}";
  str= str.substring(1,str.length()-2).trim();

  String[] notops = str.split("},");
  for (String value: notops){
      value = value.trim();
      System.out.print("key: " +  value.substring(0,keyLength) + "\t");
      System.out.print("Value: " +  value.substring((keyLength+2),value.length()));
      System.out.println();

  }
```

Comment: exactly the same, but really don't know how to group into.

Comment: this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010879/best-way-to-create-a-hashmap-of-arraylist will give you more info

Comment: (or) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134687/how-to-add-element-into-arraylist-in-hashmap

Comment: how to extract the values from the given string, storing them in the hashmap is fine and thanks for that +1

Comment: arraylist = hashmap.get("mykey");

Comment: hope you got my point wrong, I have string which has the ` {
2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}, 
6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}
}` I really don't know how to extract the value from this for the id..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38525/discussion-between-anto-and-upog)

Comment: you need to make use of regex

Comment: NP, would you help me with the regex?

Comment: I get this `[, {mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00, mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}, , {mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}]` and id is missing

Comment: what is the exact value you need to get from string

Comment: id and corresponding value for that like `2298597` and `mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00, mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL`

Comment: please help me with one more clarification, I am sorry for taking your valuable time,I have updated my question. How do i copy the values to java bean. Please have a look at my EDIT

Comment: call the corresponding setMethod and pass the value as argument e.g if Obj is an instance of your bean then obj.setMethod(value)

Comment: sure but I will have values like the following `mihpayid=403993715508464472, request_id=, bank_ref_num=2000095238, amt=50.00, disc=0.00, mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=TEST CARD DETAILS, udf2=, addedon=2013-09-19 17:36:10, status=success, unmappedstatus=captured, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=0000-00-00 00:00:00` and set the value from the above

Comment: some thing like this : http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-set-property-value-of-a-bean/