# How to add elements into ArrayList in HashMap? DART & Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Looking for an example in dart exactly like this question: [How to add element into ArrayList in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134687/how-to-add-element-into-arraylist-in-hashmap)

```
  Map<int, List<Message>> user_id_mapped_to_messages_list = new HashMap();
```

**This throws a null insert, what am I missing here?**

```
  user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id].add(message_to_current_user);
```

**Error:**

```
I/flutter (11992): ==============================================
I/flutter (11992): Message is going to the logged in user id of: 11
I/flutter (11992): Message details:
I/flutter (11992): sender: Instance of 'User'
I/flutter (11992): time: 2020-05-11 22:28:26
I/flutter (11992): text: Message 2 from John to Joe
I/flutter (11992): message added to chat group
E/flutter (11992): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
E/flutter (11992): Receiver: null
E/flutter (11992): Tried calling: add(Instance of 'Message')
E/flutter (11992): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (11992): #1      _myappnameMessagesRecentChatsState.getConversations.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
(package:myappname_app_androidx/widgets/home/messages/messages_v2/recent_chats.dart:158:83)
```

---

No items existed... for loop printing the messages in the array list

```
user_id_mapped_to_messages_list.forEach((k,v) => print('${k}: ${v}'));
```

Comment: can you show the error and the code where yoy are declaring and inserting into the lists

Comment: Added the error, the code where I'm inserting is too much to post... It's basically just: `user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id].add(message);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created user_id_mapped_to_messages_list variable of type Map> but initialised with HashMap because of that you are getting error.

it should be like below.

```
Map<int, List<Message>> user_id_mapped_to_messages_list = new Map();
```

Update:

This is happening because when you directly assign or add any value to list when it is not actually initialised, so add following line before a

```
user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id] = [];

user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id] = [];

    if (user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id] == null) {
      user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id] = [];
      user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id].add(message_to_current_user);
    } else {
      user_id_mapped_to_messages_list[user_id].add(message_to_current_user);
    }
```